# Subqueries and Large Tables. How do I Improve The Speed?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, query-optimization

I'm not new to MySQL, but I'm definitely way in over my head here.

I'd like to show a table of differences in temperatures for Panama and Belize based on date and atmospheric level. The query is supposed to match the Panama and Belize data based on date and atmospheric level and return the top 30 differences, ordered by the extent of the differences.

However, it is incredibly slow (over 30s) so it times out. Some other queries that I've written for this dataset are also very slow (about 26s). But if I only run the subqueries, they take only 1.7s or so. I should note that both of the tables below are over 440,000 rows long, though I don't think that's very large. The problem is probably the way that I'm joining the tables or the way that I'm creating the subqueries.

Here's my setup: (It's the SQL from the the exported tables. I'm omitting some columns)

```
/**The table for Panama weather data */ 

CREATE TABLE `panama_weather_data` (
  `Id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `OwmPackageId` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Level` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Temperature` float DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `panama_weather_data`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`) USING BTREE;
COMMIT;

/**The table for Belize weather data*/

CREATE TABLE `belize_weather_data` (
  `Id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `OwmPackageId` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Level` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Temperature` float DEFAULT NULL,
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `belize_weather_data`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`) USING BTREE;
COMMIT;

/**Code to populate the tables here*/
```

And here's my query:

```
SELECT ABS(PanamaTemperature-BelizeTemperature) AS TemperatureDif, 
PanamaAtmostphericLevel, PanamaTable.Dt
         FROM
         (SELECT CAST(panama_weather_data.Dt AS DATETIME) AS Dt,  
         panama_weather_data.Level AS PanamaAtmostphericLevel, 
         panama_weather_data.Temperature AS PanamaTemperature
         FROM panama_weather_data
         WHERE panama_weather_data.OwmPackageId = 'openweathermappkg19758'  ) 
         AS PanamaTable
         JOIN 
         (SELECT CAST(belize_weather_data.Dt AS DATETIME) AS Dt, 
         belize_weather_data.Level AS BelizeAtmosphericLevel, 
         belize_weather_data.Temperature AS BelizeTemperature
         FROM belize_weather_data
         WHERE belize_weather_data.OwmPackageId = 'openweathermappkg19758' ) 
         AS BelizeTable
         ON PanamaAtmostphericLevel = BelizeAtmosphericLevel
         AND PanamaTable.Dt = BelizeTable.Dt
         ORDER BY TemperatureDif
         LIMIT 30
```

My question is really: Is there anyway to optimize this query and make it less painful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CAST(panama_weather_data.Dt AS DATETIME) AS Dt

Why? (all this will do is slow down the query)

> Is there anyway to optimize this query

The SQL SELECT statement you have shown us certainly would *not* be my starting point. However you did not tell us how you intend to query the data in future. Specifically, are you really going to examine all of the data each time you run a query?

Your biggest win comes from not keeping the data in separate tables - it should be a single table with different attributes for the two datasets.

After that, the next biggest improvement would come from storing the temperature difference in the table and indexing it.

Comment: The cast to DATETIME was necessary (IMO) because I need to eventually parse the dates as JavaScript date objects and it's faster to pre-process them on the server. Unfortunately, yes all of the data would need to be assessed each time, to produce a chart showing the differences in temperature for each atmospheric level. Your suggestion (restructuring the database) is exactly what I was trying to avoid. I receive the data as two separate files and wanted to keep the information separate because it _seemed_ more simple. Obviously it isn't. Kudos.

Comment: Then cast the output of the query - **DO NOT** join the tables on a calculated field

Answer (score 0):

A way to increase speed drastically in SQL databases is to use indices. This is a tradeoff between disk space and query performance.

To find out where to put indices, search for the conditions that limit your result sets the most. In your case, you probably have a few hundred thousand rows for both tables, but you only want 30 of those, whose Atmospheric Levels and date are equal. You probably want to put an index on those two columns like so:

```
CREATE INDEX level_date_panama ON panama_weather_data (Level, Dt);
CREATE INDEX level_date_belize ON belize_weather_data (Level, Dt);
```

Please tell me if this increases your performance.

Comment: I would not expect this to improve performance - an index only improves performance if it reduces the number of rows read from the database or improves the access path; if the version of MySQL supports merge joins then one of the 2 indexes might speed things up slightly but not a great deal.

Comment: When crossing each record from Table A with a record from Table B, an index on Table B would help finding that record faster.. I don't have the dataset available but looking on the query, I wouldn't expect anything else to greatly increase the computation speed.

Comment: You are describing a nested join - which is very inefficient when you are reading all the records in table.

Comment: I've tried indices. First with the Level and Dt, as you suggested, and then with TemperatureDif using a temporary table. I tried with the latter because the `ORDER BY TemperatureDif` statement seems to be the real problem here. But in both cases the queries were still too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a few things to possibly improve performance here:

1. Remove the subqueries.

From what you posted I see no reason why the subqueries are necessary for the join. You could just as easily remove them and rewrite using the actual column names in place of where you wrote the `AS` values.

2. Input your Dt data as a Datetime

A `CAST` is not a particularly expensive operator, but does take time to complete. If you are only using these columns as Datetimes, you should be entering them as such and change the column type to a Datetime. You could directly compare these values instead of having to cast them.

3. Compare Dt as a Date

Going off of (2), if all your Dt values are Dates, casting them to Datetimes won't be doing anything to the value, so just compare on the natural Date type.

4. Index

If the above is not possible due to outside constraints, create an index based on how you are joining, this would be a column used in your ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of values are in `id`?  Perhaps you can get rid of `id`, and use `PRIMARY KEY(level, dt)`?

Why is `level` a `FLOAT`?  If they are really "floating" values, then is it realistic for both tables to have the same values?  I guess they are feet or meters above sea level?  In which case, won't `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` suffice?

Then...

```
SELECT  ABS(p.Temperature - b.Temperature) AS TemperatureDif,
        p.Level,
        p.Dt
    FROM  panama_weather_data AS p
    JOIN  belize_weather_data AS b
       USING (OwmPackageId, Level, Dt)
    WHERE  p.OwmPackageId = 'openweathermappkg19758'
    ORDER BY  TemperatureDif DESC
    LIMIT  30;
```

You will need

```
INDEX(OwmPackageId, Level, Dt)
```

with those columns in any order, and on either (or both) tables.

As already mentioned, no `CAST` is needed.  However, if you need some format other than `"2017-08-13 10:04:12"`, then use `DATE_FORMAT(...)` in the `SELECT` clause (not the `USING` clause).

Rather than having two 'identical' tables, consider having one table with an extra column for which country is involved.  This would make it easy to extend to an arbitrary number of locations.  The `SELECT` would need to be a "self join" and the syntax would be slightly different.